# Hot link prevention for Google cloud storage

Tags: web-hosting, google-cloud-storage

AWS S3 has [aws:Referer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html) bucket policy to prevent hot linking. This there similar bucket policy for Google cloud storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A restriction based on the HTTP Referer header is not currently supported for Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks. A good reason to stay away form GCS for static image hosting.